# Why is there a difference in the ordering of auto configuration classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE.

I have three gradle modules: application, integration-test and web. Application and integration-test both depend on web, web depends on a library I have written. This library has the following class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebErrorAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CatchAllExceptionHandler catchAllExceptionHandler() {
        return new CatchAllExceptionHandler();
    }

    @ConditionalOnBean(ErrorAttributes.class)
    @Bean
    public ErrorController errorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return new ErrorController(errorAttributes);
    }
}
```

The above class is included in spring.factories.

The @SpringBootApplication in the application module deploys fine, but the @SpringBootApplication in the integration-test module does not. The error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'errorController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.sample.package.ErrorController.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
to { /error}: There is already 'basicErrorController' bean method
```

I understand the cause: my own ErrorController can't be instantiated as there is already a handler defined for /error. I don't understand why this doesn't happen when deploying the application outside of the integration-test though.

How does Spring determine the order in which auto configuration classes are executed? I'm able to fix the issue by adding @AutoConfigureBefore(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class) to my WebErrorAutoConfiguration.class but I would like to understand the difference in behaviour between both modules. I've looked at the ordering of the jars loaded in the ClassLoader but my library is loaded before Spring's in both instances.

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using?

Comment: 2.1.4.RELEASE .

Answer (score 0):

The order in spring boot auto-configuration is different because they do not ensure the order unless you place annotations like `@AutoConfigureBefore`, `@AutoConfigureAfter`, etc.

When you do not specify them, it is pretty much based on your classpath (might be different between OS's, env's, build-tools's, etc) and the order spring read the list of modules. In each environment it might be slightly different and if you want to ensure the order you want is executed, you need to specify the order.

Note that anything in your main application (the one under the package with a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) will load first before everything else and the annotations mentioned that support ordering of auto-configuration modules do not affect those configurations.